# Which services are easier to test - REST or SOAP RPC ones?

Tags: testing, rest, soap, rpc

One of the crieria we are using when deciding between using REST and SOAP (RPC) style services is not just programmer convenience, but which is easier to test using Automated test tools. It seems there are lots of good tools for both, but is one inherently easier?

Comment: You know that REST is about two orders of magnitude simpler than SOAP, right? I would say the simpler one is inherently easier to test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RESTful APIs are usually simpler, and built on top of well developed technologies that are easy enough to test (specifically, HTTP), so I would say RESTful APIs may be simpler to test. You can even do most of your testing with just a web browser, so I think that's pretty simple.